# how to disable automatic created URLs from Vercel

Tags: next.js, hosting, vercel

I've hosted my NextJs project in Vercel. every time I push any changes it's creating 2 extra build URLs of the same commit. and sending an email about it. How can I disable the extra builds?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Vercel doesn't sends email. It is GitHub that is doing so. Disable the notifications (or unwatch the repo) from GitHub or put `{ "github": { "silent": true } }` in `vercel.json`. Moreover, Vercel builds it only one time and deploys it at 2-3 urls.

Comment: Ohh ok... thanks